# React router Redirect does not work when route comes from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Creating the routes in the app, I noticed that Redirect doesn't work if a Component with Routes is rendered before, I want to know why.

```
const TestRoute = () => {
  return (
      <Route exact path="/d" component={D} />
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={A} />
        <Route exact path="/b" component={B} />
        <Route exact path="/c" component={C} />
        <TestRoute />
        <Redirect to="/c" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If I delete TestRoute redirect works, I try adding Switch component in TestRoute but it does not work too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-switch-es8wt

Answer (score 2):

From the [`react-router-dom` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node), only `Route` and `Redirect` are valid children of a `Switch` component.

**BUT**

You can use a function to return more routes to render

```
const testRoute = () => <Route exact path="/d" component={D} />;

const RouterApp = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/a" component={A} />
        <Route exact path="/b" component={B} />
        <Route exact path="/c" component={C} />
        {testRoute()}
        <Redirect to="/c" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-switch]